# How to write a PL/SQL program to get rows count(no of employees) after deleting particular row (employee) using trigger?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have written this block , and I am pretty sure something is missing in here :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER
AFTER DELETE
ON Employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employees;
END;
```

Can anyone plz help me out!!

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Trg_Emp_AD AFTER DELETE ON Employees
  2    v_count INT;
  3  BEGIN
  4    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM Employees;
  5    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'There are '||v_count||' lines in the table' );
  6  END;
  7  /
  v_count INT;
  *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification
```

Comment: What are you going to do with this information?  In general, a row-level trigger on `employees` cannot query the `employees` table.  You could potentially use a statement-level trigger instead but you'll lose the context of what row(s) changed which is usually problematic.  You can have a compound trigger with row- and statement-level sections where the row-level trigger populates a collection of what changed and the statement-level trigger queries the table using that collection but that's adding a whole lot of complexity when all you've posted is a single line.

Comment: Just as an addition to Justin's comment and Barbaros' answer, for better consistency it's better to create a materialized view (refresh fast on commit), so you can easily get it, or special procedure for delete, that will return number of employees after delete in its output parameter and is it instead of pure delete with trigger. Do not forget that triggers increase complexity, affect performance and hide logic

Comment: And assuming you get the trigger working, what is it you are planning on _actually doing_ with the count when you get it?  What _business problem_ are you trying to solve with all of this.  I strongly suspect we are looking the the first stages of an x-y problem.  https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @EdStevens She is learning.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to display the result of the count, then convert the current trigger body to a the following of type *statement level*, rather than a *row level* trigger by removing `FOR EACH ROW` firstly such as

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Trg_Emp_AD AFTER DELETE ON Employees
  v_count INT;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM Employees;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'There are '||v_count||' lines in the table' );
END;
/
```

Comment: I tried this one but its giving error . It says Invalid Trigger Specification.I added the name of the trigger though.By the way I am using Oracle 19C.

Comment: yes, we've missed the name @GayatriBarhate , just fixed now.